# How to use the Java plugin in Firefox 52 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java, firefox

I am using Ubuntu Mate Xenial and can't find a way to run Java in Firefox 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox [disabled NPAPI plugins](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/) in release 52, with the exception of the Flash plugin. This means you can no longer use the Java plugin.

To continue using the Java plugin, you need to switch to Firefox 52 ESR which still supports it.

Answer (score 1):

### In case you wish to keep using the current (most up-to-date) version of Firefox but also install Firefox 51 (FF 51) in parallel, so you can use FF 51 when you need to use the JRE (Java NPAPI) plugin, you can follow these steps:

1. Open a shell terminal window as a **common user** (not root / superuser!) and then run this command in order to create an "applications" folder:

   ```
   mkdir ~/applications
   ```
2. Now **CLOSE ALL FIREFOX INSTANCES (windows)** and then run this shell command, in order to download and install the FF 51 tarball and then remove the FF 51 auto updater:

   ```
   sudo killall firefox ; if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` == 64 ]; then wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/51.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-51.0.tar.bz2 -O ~/applications/ff51.tar.bz2; else wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/51.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-51.0.tar.bz2 -O ~/applications/ff51.tar.bz2; fi; cd ~/applications ; tar -xvf ~/applications/ff51.tar.bz2 ; rm ~/applications/ff51.tar.bz2 ~/applications/firefox/updater*
   ```

   - **Note**: the above command downloads FF 51 in United States' English (`en-US`). If e.g. you want the Brazilian Portuguese version, replace `en-US` by `pt-BR` on the command above. The same logic applies to other languages. A full list of ISO language-country codes available for FF 51 can be found [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/51.0/linux-x86_64/).
3. This next command will create the **plugins** folder for your custom FF 51 install.

   ```
   if [ ! -d ~/.mozilla ]; then mkdir ~/.mozilla; fi; if [ ! -d ~/.mozilla/plugins ]; then mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins; fi; chmod -R 770 ~/.mozilla
   ```
4. Now, assuming that you're using a JRE (not a JDK), run this command in order to create a symbolic link to your JVM (Java Virtual Machine) binary file (the **java** file) inside your FF 51 plugins folder:

   ```
   if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` == 64 ]; then sudo ln -sf $(echo $(which java) | rev | cut -c10- | rev)/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/sunjava; else sudo ln -sf $(echo $(which java) | rev | cut -c10- | rev)/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/sunjava; fi
   ```
5. Create a symbolic link to FF 51 inside `/usr/bin/` so when you run the command `firefox51` the terminal starts FF 51:

   ```
   sudo ln -sf ~/applications/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox51
   ```
6. Nice! Now let's start Firefox's profile manager:

   ```
   firefox51 -P
   ```
7. A window will come up. Make sure the `Work offline` box is **unchecked** (unmarked) and that the `Use the selected profile without asking at startup` box is **checked** (marked). Also, notice that the list already has a `default` profile: this is Firefox's standard profile and so it shall remain.

   At the same window, click on `Create Profile...`, then click on `Next`, go to `Enter new profile name:` and type **ff51**. Afterwards, click on `Finish`.

   Notice that now the `ff51` profile is selected, which makes it the new standard profile. But this is **wrong**. Hence, select the `default` profile again and (only) then click on `Exit`.
8. Now run this command in order to start FF 51 with the new `ff51` profile:

   ```
   firefox51 -P ff51
   ```
9. Now that you're running FF 51, open the **about:config** URL (which is Firefox's config page), uncheck the `Show this warning again` box and click on `I accept the risk!`, then go to `Search:` and type `app.update.enabled` (this parameter defines if Firefox shall search for updates or not). If `app.update.enabled` is present and its attribute is `true`, perform a double-click on it in order to change this attribute to `false` (you can also right click onto it and then select `Toggle`, in order to invert its value).
10. Repeat the same process with the parameter `app.update.enabled`: if it's available and its attribute is `true`, change its attribute to `false`.
11. Now that profile `ff51` is created and configured to never let FF 51 perform an automatic self update, close all FF 51 windows and let's do some testing!
12. If you start your **current** Firefox, the **about:support** URL must show you that you're running the newest Firefox version, **about:profiles** must show you that the profile currently in use is `default`, and **about:config** must show you that the parameters `app.update.enable` and `app.update.auto` are set as `true`.

    If you close the current (newest) Firefox version that you have installed on your system and then start Firefox 51 (which you can do by running the shell command `firefox51 -P ff51`), then the **about:support** URL must show you that you're running Firefox version 51.0, **about:profiles** must show you that the profile currently in use is `ff51`, and **about:config** must show you that the parameters `app.update.enable` and `app.update.auto` are both set to `false`.

    Close all Firefox windows, then run the shell command `firefox` and go to the **about:preferences#advanced**, click on the `Update` tab and make sure the `Automatically install updates (recommended: improved security)` is checked (if it's not, select it), because your current Firefox must be executed with the `default` profile and such profile must be set to cause Firefox to automatically perform its self update. If such box is invisible, it means that Firefox is already configured to perform automatic self updates and this config is protected against modifications.

    Now that your **current** Firefox is properly configured, close it and the run `firefox51 -P ff51` again, then go to **about:preferences#advanced**, click on the `Update` tab and make sure that the box `Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)` is checkd (if it's not, select it), because your FF 51 install must be executed with the "alternative" profile `ff51` and such profile must be set to reject automatic self updates.

    PS: if a window pops-up on FF 51 asking you to restart the browser so it can apply the update, don't worry: just click on the "Restart" button. Because the FF 51 updater was previously deleted, FF 51 won't be able to update itself.

    Keep FF 51 open and using profile `ff51`, then go to **about:support** and make sure that you're really using FF version **51.0** (this is the full / correct version number). Also, if the NPAPI JRE plugin was detected, then if you go to **about:plugins** you'll see a `Java(TM) Plug-in` text up there. You can algo go to https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/installed8.jsp in order to check if your FF 51 browser has indeed detected and is able to run the NPAPI Java plugin.

    If the Java plugin isn't working fine, maybe it's blocked: just go to **about:addons**, click on the `Plugins` tab and, at the line of the Java plugin, select the `Always activate` option.
13. From now on, every time you need to run Firefox 51, just open a shell terminal window and run this command:

    ```
    firefox51 -P ff51
    ```
14. You can also create a `firefox51.desktop` file under `/usr/share/applications/`, which is detected by many Linux distributions as an "applications" folder and will likely (not 100% surely) make your FF 51 install visible somewhere at your distro's applications menu (assuming that your Linux distro runs a DE - Desktop Environment).

    If you don't know how to create a `.desktop` file and would like to use a shell command in order to **try** (not necessarily succeed) to create such file, run this shell command:

    ```
    sudo cp `find /usr/share/applications -iname '*firefox*.desktop' -print -quit` /usr/share/applications/firefox51.desktop ; sudo sed -i -e 's|Exec=firefox \%u|Exec=firefox51 -P ff51 \%u|' "/usr/share/applications/firefox51.desktop" ; sudo sed -i -e 's|Exec=firefox -new-window|Exec=firefox51 -P ff51 -new-window|' "/usr/share/applications/firefox51.desktop" ; sudo sed -i -e 's|Exec=firefox -private-window|Exec=firefox51 -P ff51 -private-window|' "/usr/share/applications/firefox51.desktop" ; sudo sed -i -e 's|Firefox|Firefox 51|' "/usr/share/applications/firefox51.desktop"
    ```

    - **Note**: if you want the above "supercommand" to have a slight chance to work, it is mandatory that you have a current version of Firefox installed, because the first thing the above command does is to look for a `firefox.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`, and the only chance of such file existing is if you have the current Firefox version installed (besides of FF 51).
15. If the launcher was successfully created (and properly configured), the applications menu of your Linux distro's DE will show you some application launcher having a name such as "Firefox 51" or something similar to it. This launcher will always launch Firefox 51 with the alternative profile `ff51` and this FF 51 install will never attempt to self update (and, even if it did, it would fail anyway...). As long as you keep your JRE updated and its plugin has a symlink to `~/.mozilla/plugins/sunjava`, your FF 51 install shall be able to run the Java/JRE NPAPI plugin whenever a website requests it.

**Footnotes**

- If you want to see a full list of the `about:` URLs used by Firefox, just go to **about:about**. I particularly find **about:mozilla** pretty interesting (and weird, at the same time).
- "With great power comes great responsibility": some `about:` URLs let you do things that can break your browser. Be careful. You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use another Web browser still in development, based on deprecated features of Firefox, like Pale Moon (which is basically a fork of some old Firefox version), as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1477726/614483).